# Reading multiple files synchronously in Javascript using FileReader

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization, filereader

I have a `for` loop iterating over the number of files

I have to read the first line of each file and add it let's say to a Map having File name as the key and First line of that file as a the value.

I am using `FileReader` to read the file but it is asynchronous.

When I open a stream to read the file the loop gets incremented before I am done with reading the file and adding my desired entry to the map.

I need a synchronous operation i.e. Read the First line , add it to the Map and then increment the loop and proceed with the next file.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

    var file = files[i];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    var lines = progressEvent.target.result.split('\n');
    firstLine = lines[0];
    alert('FirstLine'+firstLine);   
    //add to Map here 
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

How to modify the code so as to achieve the above mentioned functionality.

Comment: To synchronize a process you can use `recursion` or `promise chain`

Comment: @Rajesh could you please help me with it, am not a pro working with JS.

Comment: you can try something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw3cbcyo/). This is a sample code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use promises and let them run in the order you create them using `reduce`.

The below code shows how it could be done this way, and you can take a look at this simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jcd5du7/) that demos the idea.

```
//create a function that returns a promise
function readFileAndAddToMap(file){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
            var lines = progressEvent.target.result.split('\n');
            firstLine = lines[0];
            console.log('FirstLine'+firstLine);   
            //add to Map here 
            resolve();
        }

        reader.onerror = function(error){
            reject(error);
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
}

//create an array to hold your promises
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    //push to the array
    promises.push(readFileAndAddToMap(files[i]));
}

//use reduce to create a chain in the order of the promise array
promises.reduce(function(cur, next) {
    return cur.then(next);
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
    //all files read and executed!
}).catch(function(error){
    //handle potential error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, what I did was I removed the `for` loop and used `recursive function` instead. That way, I was able to handle the sequence of `FileReader`.

Below I tried to modify your code based on my logic. feel free to ask any question in comments if you need more clarity.

```
attachmentI = { i: files.length };

function UploadMe() {
   attachmentI.i--;
   if(attachmentI.i > -1){
      var file = files[attachmentI.i];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
         var lines = progressEvent.target.result.split('\n');
         firstLine = lines[0];
         alert('FirstLine'+firstLine);   
         //add to Map here
         UploadMe();
      }
   reader.readAsText(file);
   }
```